# How to underline a QLabel in a QGridLayout with Qt in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

I'm currently working with Qt 5.7-5.8 in C++ and I'm trying to underline a QLabel with a solid black line underneath it. Knowing my QLabel is inside a QGridLayout, I've tried this piece of code but it isn't displaying the line.

```
mViewerLayout->itemAtPosition(0, 0)->widget()->setStyleSheet("border-bottom: 8px solid black");
```

I've tried setting the object name and setting the stylesheet through its objectName(), I've tried writing "QWidget" instead of "QLabel" inside the quotation marks of setStyleSheet() function call in the code sample below, and I've tried without using the objectName().

```
mViewerLayout->itemAtPosition(0, 0)->widget()->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border-bottom: 8px solid black;}");
```

If I set the stylesheet to `border: 8px solid black`, then it works and covers all borders of the QLabel, but I only want to underline it and border-bottom doesn't seem to work, even though I know that's how you specify the bottom border in CSS, and even Qt documentation seems to specify this syntax. Can someone please correct me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following style sheet on the QLabel should do the trick:

```
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-radius: 0px;
```

There might be a better way, but what I see is that if you do not specify the radius, the line is not shown.

Full code to show the working:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QWidget widget;
  QVBoxLayout *l =  new QVBoxLayout(&widget);
  QLabel label;
  label.setText("This text is underlined");
  label.setStyleSheet("border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-radius: 0px;");
  l->addWidget(&label);
  l->addWidget(new QWidget());
  widget.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Do you perhaps have other stylesheets set on your application that is conflicting with the style set on the label?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I appreciate it! I've tried the stylesheet you recommended but it still doesn't display the line. I'll try some other things.

Comment: @Quoc-Minh See my updates, I have tested with Qt 5.7 and 5.9, seems to be working in stand alone example (the code). What does that example do for you in stand alone application?

Comment: Thank you! You've just now solved my problem. It seems that I had to put the label inside a QBoxLayout, and then have a QWidget act as a container to set the layout to the QBoxLayout. And then adding that container QWidget to my QGridLayout displayed the bottom border of the QLabel. I don't really understand why it doesn't display if it doesn't have a container, but oh well it works haha!

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
 QLabel * lab = static_cast<QLabel *>(mViewerLayout->itemAtPosition(0, 0)->widget());
 QFont f = lab->font();
 f.setUnderline(true);
 lab->setFont(f);
```

I think that just using the built-in underline functionality will be easier and give a better result than trying to fake it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The thing is, I'm not trying to underline some words! I would like to draw a thick line over the bottom border of the rectangle that a QLabel forms.